# IpAddrCtrl is broken on GTK

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets, wxtextctrl

I have an `IpAddrCtrl` element from `wx.lib.masked` in my simple test:

```python
import wx
import wx.lib.masked as masked

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(500,500))

        self.ipaddr1 = masked.IpAddrCtrl(self, -1, style=wx.TE_PROCESS_TAB)

        self.grid_ip = wx.FlexGridSizer(cols=2, vgap=10, hgap=10)
        self.grid_ip.Add(self.ipaddr1, 0, wx.ALIGN_LEFT)    
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.grid_ip, 0, wx.ALIGN_LEFT | wx.ALL, border=5)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)    
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT, self.OnIpAddrChange, id=self.ipaddr1.GetId())    
        self.Show(True)

    def OnIpAddrChange(self, event):
        print(self.ipaddr1.GetAddress())
        print(self.ipaddr1.IsValid())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MainWindow(None, "IpAddrCtrl sample")
    app.MainLoop()
```

After application starts, I try to insert correct numeric values in my `IpAddrCtrl` element, but it falls with following log:

```
<BaseMaskedTextCtrl: .   .   .   >
False
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-3.0-gtk2/wx/lib/masked/maskededit.py", line 3016, in _OnChar
    keep_processing = self._keyhandlers[key](event)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-3.0-gtk2/wx/lib/masked/maskededit.py", line 3937, in _OnChangeField
    self._AdjustField( pos )
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-3.0-gtk2/wx/lib/masked/maskededit.py", line 4291, in _AdjustField
    newfield = field._AdjustField(slice)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-3.0-gtk2/wx/lib/masked/maskededit.py", line 1649, in _AdjustField
    intStr = str(long(intStr))
ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: '.'
```

Here a [screencast](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61Qyz.gif) how does it actually works.

Similar [demo](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxPython/blob/master/demo/MaskedEditControls.py) from wxPython project causes same problems for me.

My environment: Debian Stretch with Python `2.7.13`, wxPython `3.0.2` and GTK2 `2.24.31-2` from official stable repositories.

Any advices?
Thanks for the help!

---

**Update:**
I try to use same sample on Win32 platform and there are no any problems with `IpAddrCtrl`. After some debugging I found out that the difference in GTK/Win versions in additional `EVT_TEXT` event call that occurs in `IpAddrCtrl` when I try to edit selected text region. That causes unnecessary `_OnTextChange` event handler call, that brokes input.
That strange behavior [described](https://wiki.wxpython.org/wxPython%20Platform%20Inconsistencies#wxTextCtrl.SetValue.28.29_from_within_Event_Handlers) on wxPython wiki and [commented](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxPython/blob/master/wx/lib/masked/maskededit.py#L2945) in a sources of base class for `IpAddrCtrl`, but currently a have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Not sure why you need `ipaddr = self.FindWindowById(event.GetId())`

Answer (score 0):

It's a horrible control, which as far as I can tell, simply doesn't function intuitively at all.
You have to press `back space`,to clear the field, as you enter each segment of the ip address or it gets itself in a complete tizzy.
Replace your lines

```
ipaddr = self.FindWindowById(event.GetId())
print ipaddr
print ipaddr.IsValid()
```

with

```
print (self.ipaddr1.GetAddress())
print (self.ipaddr1.IsValid())
```

Clearly, it's a function that needs work, as it is `broken` in wxpython 4 as well.

Comment: Thank for your reply. Sure, these lines from wx demo can be safely replaced.
Looks like I found what brokes `IpAddrCtrl`, updated in OP post.